# Recursion Haskell - minimum value function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Is there another way to do this function without the use haskell functions

```
    mymin :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a 
    mymin [] = error "empty list"
    mymin [x] = x  
    mymin (x:xs)   
          | x < mt = x  
          | otherwise = mt  
            where mt = mymin xs
```

and tell me what does `mymin :: (Ord a) => [a] ->a` mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since AndrewC already explained what `mymin :: Ord a => [a] -> a` means. An alternative function could be :

```
mymin :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a 
mymin [] = error "empty list"
mymin [x] = x  
mymin (x:y:xs) = if x < y then mymin(x:xs) else mymin(y:xs)
```

or

```
mymin :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a 
mymin [] = error "empty list"
mymin [x] = x  
mymin (x:y:xs) = mymin ((if x < y then x else y):xs)
```

Answer (score 11):

If you're not allowed to use other functions, your way is fine.

You could do

```
min' [] = error "empty list"
min' (x:xs) = minhelper x xs where
  minhelper m [] = m
  minhelper m (y:ys) | y < m = minhelper y ys
                     | otherwise = minhelper m ys
```

But I don't think it's any better than yours really for general use. It keeps track of a minimum value `m` across recursive calls.

We could rewrite minhelper's second case as

```
  minhelper m (y:ys) = minhelper (if y<m then y else m) ys
```

making use of the fact that in Haskell, if-then-else work on expressions rather than instructions.

---

```
mymin :: Ord a => [a] -> a
```

`Ord a =>` means that the mymin function works for types `a` that have inequality `(<=)` defined on them. (It's defined [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t%3aOrd).) Similarly, if it said `Eq a =>` that would mean it works for types `a` that have equality `(==)` defined on them.

`[a] -> a` means it takes a list of `a`s and gives you an `a` back.

Comment: Since OP seems to be completely fresh, it may be worth pointing out that the `<=` here is simply a less-than-or-equal function that all types that are instances of `Ord` must provide. It has nothing to do with the typographically similar `=>`, which is purely syntax.

Comment: @gspr Good idea, thanks. I've made it a bit clearer by using the word 'inequality' and giving another example, but your comment is still clearest on this point.